# Android Studio - App folder is marked red although there is no error

Tags: android-studio

I have the problem that my app folder in Android Studio is highlighted in red when there is no error and the app perfectly works. I dont know if this is coincidence but I believe the error happened after I importet some .svg files as vector assets.

This is no tragic problem but still annoys me.

[red highlighted app folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcQc7.png)

Also I cannot hover on that red stripe on the right side.

I browsed through the problem detection tool and got the same result as I suspected.
Just Warnings and Typos - no errors.

[problem detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmbgQ.png)

**What else have I tried:**

- Sync Project with Gradle Files
- Invalidate Caches and Restart
- Repair IDE

Maybe someone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like you've tried the obvious solutions! You could try changing the view from "Android" to "Project" (just above the red underlined "apps"), in case there are non-visible files causing the issue?

Comment: @JakeLee Thank you! It worked. If you choose 'Project' there are indeed non-visible files in the res folder that were causing the error...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved:

Just open the menu item "Project" below your Project name (I think it should be Android by default). You can find non-visible folders in that view causing the errors. Just delete them if not needed.

Many Thanks to @JakeLee solving it!